# Why can't I create an LVM RAID1 or mirror volume?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, mirror

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and have just added 2 new hard drives into my server. The idea being that I would create a volume group that would include them and create a bunch of logical volumes on them that would be mirrored.

I've partitioned the 2 drives to have a a primary partition on each of type 8E (LVM):

```
/dev/sdc1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sdd1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM
```

Then added them as physical devices, created a volume group and added the to the volume group:

```
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               vmdata
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  8
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                0
Open LV               0
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               3.64 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              953862
Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0   
Free  PE / Size       953862 / 3.64 TiB
VG UUID               2zdfc7-1fj2-kMdy-7OUq-eadi-AsF2-Sujbes

--- Physical volumes ---
PV Name               /dev/sdc1     
PV UUID               kAU93m-4S5V-MD1V-EkTA-m0u7-bmQn-3pyVmk
PV Status             allocatable
Total PE / Free PE    476931 / 476931

PV Name               /dev/sdd1     
PV UUID               erVnaJ-vp5S-0LHW-oRSx-joer-VXPX-KG0uDb
PV Status             allocatable
Total PE / Free PE    476931 / 476931
```

When I try to create a new logical volume of type RAID 1 it fails:

```
$ lvcreate --type raid1 -m 1 -L 64G -n fred vmdata
WARNING: Unrecognised segment type raid1
Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume : 16384 more required
Unable to allocate extents for mirror(s).
```

When I try to create it as a plain mirror it also fails:

```
$ lvcreate -m 1 -L 64G -n fred vmdata
Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume : 16384 more required
Unable to allocate extents for mirror(s).
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's been a while since I set up a LVM system, but do you perhaps need to activate the VG (`vgchange -ay vmdata`) before creating the LV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the RAID array is in an active state.

#### Example

```
$ lvscan
  inactive          '/dev/kodak_vg/lvm0' [149.00 GB] inherit
```

So I ran this command to activate it:

```
$ vgchange -ay
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "kodak_vg" now active
```

Re-running lvscan showed the LV as active now:

```
$ lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/kodak_vg/lvm0' [149.00 GB] inherit
```

#### Valid segment types

Based on the error it sounds like perhaps something is amiss with your segment types.

> WARNING: Unrecognised segment type raid1

You can use this command to find out what segment types are valid.

```
$ sudo lvm segtypes
  striped
  zero
  error
  free
  snapshot
  mirror
  raid1
  raid10
  raid4
  raid5
  raid5_la
  raid5_ra
  raid5_ls
  raid5_rs
  raid6
  raid6_zr
  raid6_nr
  raid6_nc
  thin-pool
  thin
```

#### Ubuntu 12.04's version of LVM?

The ability to create RAID's within LVM is a fairly new-ish feature, so I would suspect that 12.04's version of LVM just doesn't support this segment type.

#### What to do?

If this is the issue all is not lost. You can simply setup the LVM VG (Volume Group) on top of a MD (`mdadm`) RAID1.

*without LVM, just MD*

- [Tutorial: mdadm Software RAID on Ubuntu / Debian Systems](http://www.mysolutions.it/tutorial-mdadm-software-raid-ubuntu-debian-systems/)

*with LVM + MD*

- [How To Set Up Software RAID1 On A Running LVM System (Incl. GRUB2 Configuration) (Ubuntu 11.10)](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-lvm-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-11.10)

#### References

- [What steps can I use to recover a RAID 1 array with LVM and EXT3 on it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92711/what-steps-can-i-use-to-recover-a-raid-1-array-with-lvm-and-ext3-on-it)
- [4.4.15. RAID Logical Volumes](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/raid_volumes.html)
- [RAID5 over LVM on Ubuntu Server 12.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363920/raid5-over-lvm-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-3)

Comment: I thought about `vgchange -ay`, too but didn't say anything because IMHO the output `VG Access read/write` doesn't make sense for an inactive VG.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - yeah I wasn't sure either, I hadn't seen that msg assoc. w/ that error msgs either but is a good place to start in the debugging, IMO, just to be on the safe side. The use of LVM RAID is new to me, I've always done the `mdadm` + LVM, so the segment types was news to me.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out 12.04 didn't support raid1, but 14.04 has added it.

When I as trying to create a plain mirror (m 1) it didn't work then as it needed a 3rd volume for the mirror log.

Upgrading to 14.04 fixed it.